# add a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to add into a css property like this

[css]

```
.someclass some
{ 
///
}
```

[jquery]

```
$('.someclass some').css('behavior','url(path/something/someclass.htc)');
```

This return an error message as `"TypeError:Object Expected"`

Comment: You need to check your selector as it may not be returning the object.

Comment: post the html of element on which you want to apply this css

Comment: sometimes when you include jquery twice in the page you get this kind of a error. check whether you have mistakenly done that("TypeError:Object Expected")

Comment: Are you saying you want to use jQuery to change the style settings associated with a particular class in your stylesheet, such that both elements that already have that class and elements that are later given that class will automatically pick up the new styles?

Comment: Yes, a styled element can be modified at load/runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('.someclass some').css({'behavior' : 'path/something/someclass.htc' });
```

just copying your code for behavior property - you know it should look like this....

```
 $('.someclass some').css({'behavior' : 'url (path/something/someclass.htc)' });
```

This code will add the css property to the selector in your DOM , if you want to actually change the css file - you can not do that , but you can do this

```
 $('.yourClass').addClass('behavior');
```

the class `.behavior` you put in your css - this will have extra properties , and you dynamically add this class to the elements that you want to have it

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your CSS file, then toggle it in your JavaScript.